# Plugin Add New Installer failing

Tags: plugins, installation

I recently transferred my Wordpress Site to a new host. I have almost everything working, except for the plugin auto installer.

If I search for a plugin and install it, it works just fine.

If I try to upload my plugin from my computer, I get this error message:

Download failed. A valid URL was not provided.

I can manually install the plugin through my FTP client, Cyber Duck, by uploading the folder and activating it in the plugins list.

I have set all my permissions to 777 on my plugins folder. I do not see anything in my server error logs period.

I've had a lot of problems with setting permissions with the transfer, so I think that may be it.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Was your plugin uploaded to */uploads* directory on the server after you pressed "Upload"? If "Yes", have you added "Connection Information" after that? If "Yes" again, it could be server configuration issue.

Comment: Okay, yes, it does upload into my uploads directory. Which, I didn't think so at first, but then saw it in my media library when I went to add a picture.  I don't understand what you mean by adding connection information though.. Why are my plugins going to my uploads folder instead of my plugins folder?

Comment: Okay, got it to work. My pictures weren't uploading correctly either. So I went to Settings>Media and filled in the Full Path URL with http://www.mysite.org/wp-content/uploads and now both the pictures upload and plugins upload correctly! Voila! Two birds with one stone.

Comment: Firstly plugins goes to _/uploads_, then they are getting copied to _/plugins_ using your FTP connection information.